# Creating Auto complete textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

here's the method created, I am getting an Error that i don't seem to understand how it's coming about please help!! The **Error** is **The best Overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments**

```
void AutoCompleteText()
    {
        search_txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        search_txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conDB;
        command.CommandText = "select CCSpn_CODE,CCLname,CCFname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCcurrentDt,CCImage from abaanaCC";
       // OleDbDataReader myreader;
        conDB.Open();


        OleDbDataReader myreader = command.ExecuteReader()


            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                //tring sName = myreader["CCLname"].ToString();
                string sName = myreader.GetString(1);
                //string sName = Convert.ToString(myreader.("CCLname"));
                coll.Add(sName);
            }

            search_txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
            myreader.Close();


        conDB.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) method accepts an `int` as the parameter. You need to send the index of specified column to `GetString` like this:

```
string sName = reader.GetString(1);
```

The `1` means *the second column* change it as your need.

Or you can try this:

```
string sName = reader["CCLname"].ToString();
```

To solve this error:

> No data exists for the row/column

You should use `using` block so your code should be:

```
string sqlCmD = "select CCSpn_CODE,CCLname,CCFname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCcurrentDt,CCImage from abaanaCC";

using (OleDbConnection conDB = new OleDbConnection(address))
{
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmD, connection);

     conDB.Open();

     using(OleDbDataReader myreader = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
        if (myreader.Read())
        {
            string sName = myreader.GetString(1);
            ...
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: this is the error i am getting **no data exists for the row/column**

Comment: here's the error am getting **The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.**

Comment: @ElijahAyeeta..use my code after `conDB.Open();` also make sure you still have `command.Connection = conDB;`

Comment: @ElijahAyeeta ... If you want to use your code without `using` block I see you missed `reader.Close();`. In your code (*that you posted in the question*) add `reader.Close();` after `while`.

Comment: @ElijahAyeeta ... When you use `using` block you don't need to `myreader.Close();` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sName = reader.GetString(1);
```

should return the value in the second column  in your resultset (in your case the column CCLname).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
string sName = Convert.ToString(myreader.["CCLname"]);
```

Comment: You still have a typo in your answer that prevents it from compiling.  Maybe you should double-check that.

Comment: yah... will that do @LarsTech. Thank you for that.